# React passing parameter with arrow function in child component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have these parent and child component, I want to pass click function to select an item in child component. Yet it seems the function in child component become automatically called instead of waiting until the user click the element. To make it clearer here is my parent and child components

```
export class ParentView extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedItem: {}
  }

  handleClick = (item) => {
    alert('you click me');
    this.setState({selectedItem: item});
  } 

  render() {
    let item = { name: 'Item-1' };
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildItem item={item} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class ChildItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {item, handleClick} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <a  onClick={handleClick(item)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Those are my components using arrow function to pass `handleClick` to child component, yet alert always being called at first render without being triggered by user. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should pass a function itself to `onClick`, not a result of the passed function invocation.

If you would like to invoke it with param, you have options:

- bind it with `item` with `handleClick.bind(this, item)`. `bind` creates a new function will have a predefined first parameter - `item`
- pass new arrow function like `() => handleClick(item)`

An example below:

```
export class ChildItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { item, handleClick } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={() => handleClick(item)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In your code you're invoking a function in `onClick` declaration, so the result of `handleClick` execution will be passed to `onClick`, what is most likely not something you wanted to achieve.

> `<a onClick={handleClick(item)} />`

Update:

as @dhilt wrote, there is a drawback of such approach. Since the newly created arrow function and `.bind` also creates new function every time the `render` method of `ChildItem` is invoked, react will threat the resulted react element as a different, comparing to the previous "cached" result of `render` method, that means that likely it might lead to some performance problems in the future, there is even a rule regarding this problem for [eslint](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md), but you shouldn't just follow this rule because of two points.

1. `performance problems` should be measured. we don't forbid using `Array.prototype.forEach` in favor of a regular `for` because `for` is the same or "faster".
2. definition of click handlers as class properties leads to increasing of the initializing step of the component instance. Re-render is fast and efficient in react, so sometimes the initial rendering is more important.

Just use what's better for you and likely read articles like this https://medium.com/@ryanflorence/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Comment: thanks, I solve it with `onClick={() => handleClick(item)}`

Comment: What I don't get here is how the item gets passed to handleClick since the parameters are empty for the arrow function.  How is that working?

if I had onClick = {this.handleClick} and a function:

handleClick = element => {//stuff} 

How does element ever get passed in?

Comment: @Accribus element itself (I presume you're referring to react element) will not be passed for `onClick = {this.handleClick}`, but event will be passed instead. `onClick={ () => handleClick(item) }` here you can pass `item` manually

Comment: @uladzimir I think Accribus means to ask how we are using item in the arrow function's definition when it is not being passed as an argument? As far as i understand, here item is being resolved using lexical scoping. That is, item in the arrow function definition will be resolved to the item declared in render method because the arrow function is defined in the lexical environment of render method. Am i correct?

Comment: Thanks for this questions, but can you share how to write test case for ParentView component to pass handleClick(item) using jest ?

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer has a performance hit: `ChildItem` component will be re-rendered even if data hasn’t changed because each render allocates a new function (it is so because of `.bind`; same with arrow functions). In this particular case it is very easy to avoid such a problem by getting handler and its argument right from the `props` on new public class field:

```
export class ChildItem extends Component {

  onClick = () => {
    this.props.handleClick(this.props.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a  onClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`ParentView` remains untouched.

Comment: Does it make any difference if we use class or just function component in this case?

Comment: @Leff Sure. How you are going to define onClick in case of function component? It will be equal to defining it on render of class component, which we want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The **ES6** way:

Using arrow functions =>

```
onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
```

---

(@havenchyk's answer is the **ES5** way).